# user in docker image losing permissions to subdirectories in /tmp and /var/run

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, permissions

I'm attempting to deploy a docker container in k8s that creates its own subdirectory under `/var/run`, but any of that directory's subdirectories do not appear to retain their permissions. The docker image is running as a less privileged user than root. I am running this in k8s, and k8s' livenessCheck will exec on the pod and inspect files under `/var/run/myapp/somesubdir` (similar in spirit to how `/proc` and other directories expose information).

In code, at application startup, the following files are written by the code: `/var/run/myapp/test` and `/var/run/myapp/somesubdir/test-2`. In code, I see permission denied errors when attempting to write those files.

Example of one of the errors:

```
threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/run/myapp/somesubdir/test-2
```

The docker file:

```
RUN adduser --system --disabled-password app-user && \
    groupadd app && \
    usermod -a -G app app-user && \
    mkdir -p /var/run/myapp/somesubdir && \
    chown -Rv app-user:app /var/run/myapp && \
    chmod -Rv 664 /var/run/myapp

USER app-user
# ...
```

What I am seeing if I exec onto the pod

```
app-user@mypod:/app$ stat /var/run/myapp/
  File: /var/run/myapp/
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10008fh/1048719d    Inode: 12310926    Links: 3
Access: (0664/drw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  102/app-user)   Gid: ( 1000/     app)

app-user@mypod:/app$ stat /var/run/myapp/somesubdir
stat: cannot stat '/var/run/myapp/somesubdir': Permission denied
```

The output of chown and chmod confirm that the changes are making it to all subdirs. Is this expected behavior? Is it something to do with it being under /var/run?

**Edit**

I've tried switching to `/tmp`, and I get the same exact issue.

Comment: found the answer after some researching. nothing to do with which directory.

Answer (score 0):

The chmod needs to include execute permissions for the directory